# need help for calculating parametric equations of the trajectory of a point in a plane

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I have the following (apparently simple) problem:

> A point $P$ is moving downwards with constant speed $|v|=1$ along a vertical line of equation $x = 5\pi$.
>   At time $t=0$, $P$ has cartesian coordinates $(5\pi, 25)$ so obviously at time $t$: $P(5\pi, 25-t)$.
>
> A point $M$ needs to reach point $P$, starting from the origin $O$; at $t=0$, $M(0,0)$.
>   $M$ is constantly adjusting its trajectory so that it is always on the shortest path from $O$ (not $M$) to $P$.
>   So, if $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the parametric coordinates of $M$ as functions of time, $y(t) = \frac{(25-t)}{5\pi} x(t)$
>
> $M$ is moving with constant speed $V$ of norm $3$: $\left(\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2 = 9$.

The question is: **when will $M$ reach $P$?**

I did not manage to calculate $x(t)$ or $y(t)$.

Comment: This does seem surprisingly challenging. In what context did this question arise?

Comment: It is a riddle (among more than 1000) on web site

Comment: Actually point M is an ant. 
Point P is a drop of honey, falling along a generatrix of a right cylinder with height 25 cm and radius 5 cm, with speed 1 cm/s. 
At t=0 the ant is at the bottom of the cylinder , diametrically opposed to P.
The ant has a constant speed of 5 cm/s
Obviously one have to unfold the cylinder to start.
Looks simple, but I also find it challenging

Comment: a cat chasing a mouse be like

Answer (score 1):

From your problem, we have the following
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}\\
1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 &= \left(\frac{3}{x'(t)}\right)^2 \quad\Longrightarrow \quad \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} = \frac{3}{x'(t)}.
\end{align} 
Also
\begin{equation}
y = \frac{25-t}{5\pi}x \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y'(t) = -\frac{1}{5\pi}x(t) + \frac{25-t}{5\pi} x'(t).
\end{equation}
Thereofore
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x} = -\frac{x}{5\pi} \frac{1}{x'(t)} = -\frac{x}{15\pi}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}.
\end{align}
Denote $y_x' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ we deduce
$$ y'_x - \frac{y}{x} = -\frac{x}{15\pi}\sqrt{1 + \left(y'_x\right)^2}$$
In other words,
$$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'_x = -\frac{1}{15\pi}\sqrt{1+(y'_x)^2}$$

Comment: So I took derivative in term of $t$ both sides and used the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$ to derive that.

Comment: $y(t) = \frac{25-t}{5\pi}x(t)$, thus $$y'(t) = \left(\frac{25-t}{5\pi}\right)' x(t) + \frac{25-t}{5\pi}x'(t) = -\frac{1}{5\pi} x(t)+\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}x'(t)$$

Comment: I did make a mistake

Comment: I think this is a big improvement. Thank you Sean.
When I enter the ODE in Maple (which I downloaded yesterday, so I'm not an expert), I get a huge expression involving hyper-geometric function which I don't understand. I have added the initial condition that y(0) = 0.
I need anyway to calculate the time required for x(t) = 5Pi.
Is there any way to calculate x(t) explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, Sean, this looks right. The approach of eliminating $t$ is successful. But I can't integrate your final ODE. :(

Comment: Yes, in fact, I failed to solve the last ODE too!

Comment: I think we can solve it numerically for sure to obtain the value for $t$. I am not sure about solving it analytically, maybe we need a trick that I don't know.